# Reference request: the comparison theorem for the étale fundamental group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, fundamental-group

I am looking for exact references for the comparison theorem for the  étale fundamental group.
I mean the following result:

> **Theorem** (Grothendieck). For a pointed algebraic variety $(X,x)$ over $\mathbb{C}$ there is a canonical isomorphism
>   between the  étale  fundamental group $\pi_1^{\text{ét}}(X,x)$ and the profinite completion of the topological fundamental group
>   $\pi_1^{\rm top}(X(\mathbb{C}),x)$.

(I am interested in the case when $X$ is nonsingular.)

I could not find this assertion in SGA1 or in the book "Galois Groups and Fundamental Groups" by Tamás Szamuely. Please help!

Comment: This is Corollary 5.2 in SGA 1, Exposé XII.

Comment: As everyone else pointed out, this is SGA1, Exposé XII, Cor 5.2. Since you also said that you couldn't find it on Szamuely's book I wanted to add that you can find it there as Thm 5.7.4. (I have not enough reputation to add this as a comment).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is in SGA1, Exposé XII, Section 5.

Answer (score 1):

See also Artin-Mazur "Etale Homotopy", Ch. 12.